How to perform an action after a hangfire background job fails and exhaust its max number of retries
I have an operation being performed as Hangfire background job like this:
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => PerformActionA(param1, param2));

If the job with jobId gets failed and made max number of retries, I want to make an email notification:
NotifyUser.NotifyAboutFailedPerformActionAsync();

How do I perform this notification service after that job gets failed? There are various jobs that I am creating so I want to perform this email notification only for this operation PeformActionA.
I am new to Hangfire.

You could try following code works to apply a global filter.
Assume you have the job is like
        [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 3, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Fail)]
        public void PerformActionA(string userName,int userId)
        {

            throw new Exception("failure");
        }

Then you could create a global filter like following
    public class JobFailureFilter : IApplyStateFilter
    {
        public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {
            string methodName = context.BackgroundJob.Job.Method.Name;
            if (methodName == "PerformActionA")
            {
                if (context.NewState is FailedState failedState)
                {
                    string userName = (string)context.BackgroundJob.Job.Args[0];
                    int userId = (Int32)context.BackgroundJob.Job.Args[1];

                    NotifyUser.NotifyAboutFailedPerformActionAsync(userName,userId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {

        }

    }

Then apply this filter to program.cs
builder.Services.AddHangfire(x=> {
    x.UseSqlServerStorage(xxx);
});
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new JobFailureFilter());

